# Select Box Invisible on screen

Tags: html, vuejs2, vue-component

I have code that loops over a very simple object and displays the object elements as options in a select box.  The code looks like it is working when looking at page elements, but for whatever reason the drop down box itself is not being displayed on the browser.

The script is showing the correct results in the elements view when I inspect the page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dJ6K.jpg

I have other projects that use this same logic without issue.  I am using materialize CSS with this project, but cant confirm if that is where the issue is coming from.   Creating cards with the same looping logic works fine.  Outputting the result in 'p' tags also works with the looping logic.  I just cant make it work in 'select' + 'option' tags.

```
<template>
    <div class="add-catch container">
        <div class="formbox">
            <select size="1" v-model="selected">
                <option v-for="person in people" v-bind:key="person.key">{{person.name}} </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    name: 'AddCatch',
    data(){
        return{
            selected: null,
            people:[
                {name: "billy", key:"1234"},
                {name: "steve", key:"5367"},
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
    }
}
</script>
<style>


</style>
```

Comment: From the docs: "Remember that this is a jQuery plugin so make sure you initialize this in your document ready." https://materializecss.com/select.html

Comment: would this be true for even basic select elements?  @TommyF.   Even when I delete the CSS associated and build a basic select with hardcoded options I still can not see my dropdown menu box.

Comment: I'm not using materialize so I'm not sure, but that seemed the most plausible explanation to your issues. If you can provide a codesandbox that highlights the problem, people will be much likelier be able to help you.